# How can I run concat for cases without any scripts?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-concat

As a part of my `Gruntfile.js`:

```
...

concat: {

    ...

    js: {
        src: [
            'src/**/*.js'
        ],
        dest: 'build/js/main.js',
        nonull: true
    }
},

...
```

How can I prevent concat from generating a blank `main.js` if my `src` directory contains no scripts? Must I really create a separate task if I know I won't need to build any scripts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly a proper solution, but I managed to find a package called `grunt-cleanempty` which I set to run after `concat` to delete any generated empty files.

Comment: thats the only option you have! see this: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat/blob/master/tasks/concat.js#L111, the file is written, regardless on contents